# How to get wget to accept files with no suffix

Tags: regex, wget

I'm using `wget` (from perl) to get web pages from a site.  I'm really only interested in the `html`,`htm`,`php`,`asp`,`aspx` file types.  However, at least one site has supplied links using file names with no extensions/suffix.  I need those too.

My:

```
wget -A html,htm,php,asp,aspx
```

works great, except for the no suffix links.

I've tried a number of regex strings to try and get the no suffix pages, but to no avail.  wget returns just the main page.  So far, the only way to get these files is to open it up to all files (which isn't terrible for this website, but would be terrible for others).

Is there either a regex or regular way to specify I want links from wget with no suffixes?

Comment: If you are just interested in html pages you could try --force-html. Otherwise you might be able to use a pattern such as ^$ which will match the empty string?

Answer (score 1):

wget version 1.14 seems to support a `--accept-regex` argument which is matched against the full URL, i.e. something like the following should in theory work (untested):

```
wget --accept-regex '/[^.]+(?:\.(?:html?|php|aspx?))?$'
```

Or perhaps it would be easier to just reject those extensions you do not want?